# How to record streaming audio to the server

Tags: flash

i'm trying to create an application in flash that will record the sound from the user and will save the data on the server.
is it possible ?
should i use other language ?

Answer (score 2):

Capturing audio within Flash is relatively easy. The tricky part is getting the audio on to the server.

If your budget, skillset and hosting platform allows you should look at running an [RMTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) such as the Flash Media Server. This would provide real time streaming of audio to the server.

If you are stuck with a conventional web server you could achieve a workaround by sending the captured audio to a server-side script by POST. This wouldn’t be ideal - you would have to devise a system to trigger the HTTP POST once the audio was captured, and you would be subject to any file size limits (typically 2MB if you are using PHP to process the POST).

Whether Flash is the right tool depends on you application. You will be faced with similar challenges whatever language/technology you use. At least Flash makes the audio capture a fairly trivial process.